# Mysql database hang when processlist goes above 100 connections in raspberry pi

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, raspberry-pi

I am writing service in hibernate with c3p0 concept.And this service deployed to Raspberry pi.The **raspbery pi** having 512 mb RAM.I am hit the service continuously, when the processlist goes above 100 connections the mysql hanging up.And my service are not working. After restarting mysql only all processlist killed them self.Then services are working properly till the processlist reach above 100 connections.

My c3p0 configurations are(**hibernate.cfg** file),

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    <!-- Database connection settings -->
         <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">mani</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin</property>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>        
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <!-- <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property> -->
        <property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">10</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">100</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTime">1800</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTimeExcessConnections">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">30</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.validate">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">SELECT 1</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckin">true</property> 
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">false</property>                      
        <!-- Mention here all the pojo classes along with their package name -->
        <mapping class="com.nutans.objects.Dialog" />
        <mapping class="com.nutans.objects.Office" />
        <mapping class="com.nutans.objects.Welcome" />
        <mapping class="com.nutans.objects.Sports"/>

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Help me out!

Comment: Why do you need 100 connections? You are using connection pool so don't you think that lower number of them will be sufficient for you (10, 20 ,50) - decreasing max number of connections should help`<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>`?